# Best way to do Python table like data transformation

Tags: python, python-3.x

Given a tab-delimited string data, where columns are in the first row - there can be any number of columns in any order

```
<COLUMNS> BathsFull BathsHalf BedsTotal MatrixModifiedDT Status </COLUMNS>
<DATA> 1 1 3 2020-06-21T07:48:04.327 ACTV </DATA>
<DATA> 2 0 3 2020-06-03T09:30:38.177 ACTV </DATA>
<DATA> 1 0 2 2020-08-31T09:45:45.430 ACTV </DATA>
```

I always need to produce output like:

```
<COLUMNS> BedsTotal Status </COLUMNS>
<DATA> 3 ACTV </DATA>
<DATA> 3 ACTV </DATA>
<DATA> 2 ACTV </DATA>
```

What would be the best way to do this transformation in python? (Basically selecting a subset of columns)
Thank you for your help & ideas!

Comment: That looks suspiciously compatible with CSV. Have you tried treating this as CSV?

Comment: The hacky way would be to just do a `row.split` and take the relevant columns.

Comment: The less hacky way would be to parse each row into a data structure, and then print back only the relevant information.

Comment: thanks @MisterMiyagi - i think this might be the easiest and best option - to read it as csv

Answer (score 2):

```
import csv
import io

output = io.StringIO()

data = """<COLUMNS> BathsFull   BathsHalf   BedsTotal   MatrixModifiedDT    Status  </COLUMNS>
<DATA>  1   1   3   2020-06-21T07:48:04.327 ACTV    </DATA>
<DATA>  2   0   3   2020-06-03T09:30:38.177 ACTV    </DATA>
<DATA>  1   0   2   2020-08-31T09:45:45.430 ACTV    </DATA>"""
#print(data)
    

fieldnames = ['<COLUMNS>', 'BedsTotal', 'Status', '</COLUMNS>']
writer = csv.DictWriter(output, fieldnames=fieldnames, delimiter='  ', extrasaction='ignore')
writer.writeheader()


c = csv.DictReader(data.splitlines(), delimiter='   ')
for row in c:
    #print(row['Status'])
    writer.writerow(row)

print(output.getvalue())
output.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

**STEP 1:**
Use Pandas library.

```
import pandas as pd
```

**Step 2:**
Create a dataframe df (which is basically a table, and df is the name of your dataframe, basically you can name it whatever you want)

```
data = [[1, 1, 3, '2020-06-21T07:48:04',327], [2, 0, 3, '2020-06-03T09:30:38',177]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['BathsFull', 'BathsHalf', 'BedsTotal' ,'MatrixModifiedDT', 'Status'])
```

**Step 3:**
perform some functions like : `df.columns` or `df['BedsTotal', 'Status']` to name the columns or to select the columns, and you'll get the desired output.